# Compare column values vs. measure from another table (scatterplot highlighting)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to highlight points in a PowerBI report based on user input, based on http://sqljason.com/2018/03/highlighting-scatter-charts-in-power-bi-using-dax.html

My work so far is available at https://github.com/turbomam/measureIntoColumn/blob/master/mtminimal.pbix

My input data (`Sheet1`) consists of three columns:  the name of a car, its fuel economy (mpg) and its engine displacement.

I have created another table (`CarNames`)

> `CarNames = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Sheet1[carname])`

And added a measure to indicate the selected car

> `SelectedCar = SELECTEDVALUE(CarNames[carname])`

I have added the following to my report (counter-clockwise from upper right):

- a scatter plot of the fuel economy vs. engine displacement
- a slicer based on `CarNames[carname]`
- a card that confirms the values of the `CarNames[SelectedCar]` measure

[image]

Now I would like to highlight (not filter) the user-selected car on the scatterplot.

[image]

I thought I could create a new Boolean column for every row of `Sheet1` by testing `Sheet1[carname]` against `CarNames[SelectedCar]`.  Then I could use that Boolean value in the legend slot for my scatterplot and get a different color for the selected car.

> `CarSelected = if(Sheet1[carname] = CALCULATE(CarNames[SelectedCar]), TRUE, FALSE)`

But when I go to the table viewer, all of the `Sheet1[CarSelected]` values are `FALSE`

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to use a boolean column in your scenario. Calculated columns are **static** - they are calculated only once (upon creation or data refresh), and can't respond to slicers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149070/power-bi-filter-column-by-slicer/52150302#52150302

Comment: Thanks.  Do you understand how the highlighting is being implemented in http://sqljason.com/2018/03/highlighting-scatter-charts-in-power-bi-using-dax.html ? I'm having a hard time teasing that apart from the aggregation aspect.